# Terraform script to list out ability to dynamic variable names for use in terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I would like to define and declare same resources of different resource groups in terraform.

The end goal is to get all the resources created which are part of the specific resource group which I select from the command line when I run terraform plan. Below is the terraform script I tried to run but not sure whether the below definition an declaration is correct.Please suggest me how to write or format this script. I am new to terraform ad explore many blogs to create the below script but need clarification.

Here is the below 2 resource groups with resource variable names.
var.tf:

```
variable "properties" {

 type = object( {
    resourcegroup_name = string
    location = string
    keyvault_name = string
    Networksecuritygroup_name = string
    Storageaccount_name = string
    Storageaccount_dev = string
    APImanagement_name = string
    APP-serviceplan_name = string
    webappservice_name = string
    SQLDatabase_name = string
    NetworkInterface_name = string
    VirtualMachine_name = string
    EndPoint = string
    CDNProfile = string
    ApplicationInsigt_name = string
    TrafficManagerProfile_name = string
    SQLServer_name = string
    Subnet_name = string
    
})
variable "resourcegroup1" {
 default = [{
   
    resourcegroup_name = "001-rg"
    location = "UK South"
    keyvault_name = "kv-001"
    TrafficManagerProfile_name = "tmp-001"
    Storageaccount_name = "stg001"
    APImanagement_name = "apm-001"
    APPserviceplan_name = "asp-001"
    webappservice_name = "was-001"
    Storageaccount_dev = "devstg001"
    SQLDatabase_name = "DB-001"
    NetworkInterface_name = "NIC-01"
    VirtualMachine_name = "VM001"
    EndPoint1 = "stg001 (stg001/stg001)"
    CDNProfile1 = "cdn_001"
    EndPoint2 = "devstg001 (devstg001/devstg001)"
    CDNProfile2 = "cdn_dev001"
    ApplicationInsigt_name = "AI-001"
    SQLServer_name = "Db-server-001"
    Subnet_name = "subnet001"
    }]
},
variable "resourcegroup2" {
 default = [{
   
    resourcegroup_name = "002-rg"
    location = "UK South"
    keyvault_name = "kv-002"
    TrafficManagerProfile_name = "tmp-002"
    Storageaccount_name = "stg002"
    APImanagement_name = "apm-002"
    APPserviceplan_name = "asp-002"
    webappservice_name = "was-002"
    Storageaccount_dev = "devstg002"
    SQLDatabase_name = "DB-002"
    NetworkInterface_name = "NIC-02"
    VirtualMachine_name = "VM002"
    EndPoint1 = "stg002 (stg002/stg002)"
    CDNProfile1 = "cdn_002"
    EndPoint2 = "devstg002 (devstg002/devstg002)"
    CDNProfile2 = "cdn_dev002"
    ApplicationInsigt_name = "AI-002"
    SQLServer_name = "Db-server-002"
    Subnet_name = "subnet002"
    }]
}
```

main.tf:

```
    terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "2.90.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  # Configuration options
  features{}
}
data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {}

resource "azurerm_key_vault" "keyvault" {
  name                        = "${var.keyvault_name}"
  location                    = "${var.location}"
  resource_group_name         = "${var.resourcegroup_name}"
  enabled_for_disk_encryption = true
  tenant_id                   = "${data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id}"
 
  sku_name = "standard"

  access_policy {
    tenant_id = "987654"
    object_id = "123456"

    key_permissions = [
      "Get",
    ]

    secret_permissions = [
      "Get",
    ]

    storage_permissions = [
      "Get",
    ]
  }
}
#---------------------------------------API Management Serrvice---------------------------------------
variable "apimAdminEmail"{
default= "abc@gmail.com"
}
variable "apimTier"{
default= "Developer_1"
}
variable "apimCapacity"{
default= "1"
}
variable "hostName"{
default= "api3"
}
resource "azurerm_api_management" "APIM" {
  name                = "${var.APImanagement_name}"
  location            = "${var.location}"
  resource_group_name = "${var.resourcegroup_name}"
  publisher_name      = "API"
  publisher_email     = "${var.apimAdminEmail}"
  

   
    sku_name     = "${var.apimTier}"
    #capacity = "${var.apimCapacity}"
  

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }

  
}
```

Comment: And what exactly is the question? Does that not work (probably does not since you have a variable declaration within a variable)? How would you want to call / use those variables and modules? What is `var.resourcegroup_name`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite sure about your question but I am assuming that you want two deploy two different environments using a single main.tf **( common template for two different environments)**
***example: Dev and Stage environment.***

If that is your case, Configure two separate variable.tf files for each environment and pass the variable.tf file to when initializing the terraform.

***Please check the below Example***

1. Create Two varaible file with diffrent name (dev.tfvars and stage.tfvars)

**dev.tfvars**

```
resourcegroup_name = "002-rg"
location = "UK South"
keyvault_name = "kv-002"
TrafficManagerProfile_name = "tmp-002"
```

**stage.tfvars**

```
resourcegroup_name = "001-rg"
location = "UK South"
keyvault_name = "kv-001"
TrafficManagerProfile_name = "tmp-001"
```

2. Declare defaults for each variable

**variables.tf**

```
variable "resourcegroup_name" {
    default = ""
}
variable "location" {
    default = ""
}
....
```

4. when running the terraform automation, pass the var fie which you have created

```
terraform init
terraform plan -var-file="dev.tfvars"
terraform apply -var-file="dev.tfvars"
```

Comment: thanks for responding. but my question is if I select specific resource group via command line then resources should be created under it.So while running terraform script I would like to pass resource group name so that defined resources or specific resources should be created under that resource group. Here resource group names are different but resources types which I want to create are same.So please let me know in this requirement how my terraform script should look like..Appreciate your help.

Comment: @Vijaya I get your point. Perhaps terraform map variable type help you!